# Improving Code: Capitalizing the first and third letter of a string

Tags: python-3.x, string, function, capitalize

This is the first time I am learning python. I have had two C programming classes during my undergraduate days (many years back). I usually understand basic algorithms, but struggle to write codes out.

Currently doing a course in UDEMY, and the problem requires us to capitalize the first and third letters of the string. I have written the code (took me a while) and it works, but I know it is not pretty.

Please note: Trying to code it without using the enumerate function.

```
def wordplay(text):

    first = text[0:1]                                             #isolate the first letter
    third = text[2:3]                                             #isolate the third letter
    
    firstc = first.capitalize()                                   #capitalize the first letter
    thirdc = third.capitalize()                                   #capitalize the third letter
    changedword = firstc + text[1:2] + thirdc + text[3:]          #change the first and third letter to capital in the string
    
    print(changedword)
```

The code worked, but looking to improve my logic (without using enumerate)

Comment: `enumerate` is functionally equivalent to just using `range(len(...))`. But it's not really necessary to use either, as you've demonstrated.

Comment: BTW, I suggest using `.upper()` instead of `.capitalize()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one option which uses the `capitalize()` function:

```py
inp = "hello"
output = inp[0:2].capitalize() + inp[2:].capitalize()
print(output)  # HeLlo
```

The idea here is to just capitalize two substrings, one for the first two letters and the other for the remainder of the string.

Comment: Thank you very much. This looks much better than the ugly bit of code I worked out.

Comment: If you dont mind me asking, how did "output = inp[0:2].capitalize() + inp[2:].capitalize()" ensure the rest of the string input stayed the same? as I would think inp[0:2] will capitalize the first two letters instead of only the first...?

Comment: @aaoleeloo No... `capitalize()` only uppercases the first letter of a string.  You could use `upper()`, but I believe you would need more string manipulation.